# Writing to file error: "Too many files open"

Tags: arrays, matlab, text

I want to write the array `cloud` which is nothing abut a array storing the coordinates of a circular cloud with two columns, of latitude and longitude. I want these coordinates to be written on a text file in a manner like this.

```
 418.9517   43.9866
 419.2260   44.1501
 419.4826   44.3402
 419.7190   44.5550
 419.9327   44.7923
 420.1217   45.0497
```

With this code i want to generate multiple no of such files storing the coordinates of a single cloud in one file.

Here `a` is array with first two columns of latitude and longitude (center of circle) and the third one radius of the circle. And `z =size(a)`.(which is 2905x3). So that makes a total of 2905 files to be written.

```
for s =1:z(1)
    r= a(s,3);

    ang=0:0.1:2*pi; 
    xp=a(s,1) + r*cos(ang);  
    yp=a(s,2) + r*sin(ang);  
    xp=xp';
    yp= yp';
    cloud = [xp,yp]

    filename = ['Shower_Cloud',s,'number.txt']
    file_id = fopen (filename,'w');
    fprintf(file_id,'%g\t',cloud[]);
    fclose(file_id);
end
```

The error when i run the code is the main problem i'm not able to diagnose this problem on my own, although i have a feeling its a minor one.

```
     >> xyz
     D:\Users\Vikram\Documents\MATLAB\Manuela\Version_2\Weather\Shower\xyz.m:
     Too many files open; check that FILES = 20 in
     your CONFIG.SYS file.

     Unexpected error status flag encountered.  Resetting to proper state.
```

Please ask if i missed on something important to mention.

Comment: Try removing the `[]` after `cloud` in the `fprintf` command...

Comment: @EitanT - Still the same error.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Okay..i restarted Matlab...now i have a different error - 

Error using fprintf
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to
generate a valid file identifier.

Error in xyz (line 39)
        fprintf(file_id,'%g\t',cloud);

Comment: Could you run it with `dbstop if error` and describe all the variables at the time the problem occurs? As a sidenote, you may want to reconsider creating 2905 files if you don't have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a guess but one could expect strange behavior when concatenating numbers with strings.
You may want to use `num2str(s)` in creating the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe other parts of your program lose track of opened files. Use `fopen('all')` to list filehandles of open files. This is maybe a starting point for hunting down the bug.

Comment: How's that, if he closes each opened file in the same iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely is that some bug at some point in your code caused many files to be opened without being closed.  Note that even though the code you posted does indeed close every file correctly, if you are still running the same MATLAB session you may still have files open.

You can close all currently open files like so:

```
fclose all
```

So I suggest you type that into the MATLAB prompt first.  If you are still having the error, having a look at:

```
fopen all
```

which lists all currently open files; hopefully this will give you enough information to find the problem.